# How to get many sum of child columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two tables, `Member` and `MemberRecord`.

This are their relationship:

```
# Member Model
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :member_records, :dependent => :destroy
end
# MemberRecord Model
class MemberRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

In `MemberRecord` There are many columns: `two_pointer_attempt, two_pointer_made, three_pointer_attempt, three_pointer_made, free_throws_attempt, free_throws_made, offensive_rebound, defensive_rebound, assist, block, steal, turnover, foul, score`

Can I get those columns sum in more efficient way?

This is what I did so far:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :member_records, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :name, :number, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :team_id
  validates_inclusion_of  :number, in: 0..99

  def sum_two_pointer_made
    self.member_records.sum(:two_pointer_made)
  end

  def sum_two_pointer_attempt
    self.member_records.sum(:two_pointer_attempt)
  end

  def sum_two_pointer_total
    sum_two_pointer_made + sum_two_pointer_attempt
  end

  def sum_three_pointer_made
    self.member_records.sum(:three_pointer_made)
  end

  def sum_three_pointer_attempt
    self.member_records.sum(:three_pointer_attempt)
  end

  def sum_three_pointer_total
    sum_three_pointer_made + sum_three_pointer_attempt
  end

  def sum_free_throws_made
    self.member_records.sum(:free_throws_made)
  end

  def sum_free_throws_attempt
    self.member_records.sum(:free_throws_attempt)
  end

  def sum_free_throws_total
    sum_free_throws_made + sum_free_throws_attempt
  end

  def sum_offensive_rebound
    self.member_records.sum(:offensive_rebound)
  end

  def sum_defensive_rebound
    self.member_records.sum(:defensive_rebound)
  end

  def sum_assist
    self.member_records.sum(:assist)
  end

  def sum_block
    self.member_records.sum(:block)
  end

  def sum_steal
    self.member_records.sum(:steal)
  end

  def sum_turnover
    self.member_records.sum(:turnover)
  end

  def sum_foul
    self.member_records.sum(:foul)
  end

  def sum_score
    self.member_records.sum(:score)
  end

end
```

Comment: This will also work `MemberRecord.sum(:two_pointer_made)` is it efficient or not, not sure

Comment: `self.includes(:member_records).sum(:two_pointer_made)` It will only load  member_records which has some value, not all the `member_records`

Comment: Thanks, 
However, things I want to do are like this, `@member.member_records.sum(:two_pointer_made, : two_pointer_attempt, ... etc.)` Get all the column value in a query. But this doesn't work.

Comment: Can we do this `@member.joins(:member_records).select("member_records.*, SUM(member_records.two_pointer_made), SUM(member_records.two_pointer_attempt)").
  group("member_records.id")`

Comment: Hi, Sontya, I tried this before, it doesn't work. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an example with two columns and you can extend it for your number of columns.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # add associations here as already present

  MR_SUM_COLUMNS = %w{
    assist
    block
  } # add more member record columns here

  MR_SUM_COLUMNS.each do |column|
    define_method "member_record_#{column}_sum" do
      member_record_sums.send(column)
    end
  end

  private

  def member_record_sums
    @_member_record_sums ||=
      begin
        tn = MemberRecord.table_name

        sums_str =
          MR_SUM_COLUMNS.map do |c|
            "SUM(#{tn}.#{c}) AS #{c}"    
          end.join(', ')

        self.member_records.select(sums_str).first
      end
  end
end

m = Member.first
s1 = m.member_record_assist_sum
s2 = m.member_record_block_sum
```

Explanation:

In `ActiveRecord`'s `select` method, you can store the sum of a column as a particular value. For example:

```
# you have only two members with ids 1 and 2
m = Member.select("SUM(id) AS id_sum").first
m.id_sum #=> 3
```

So we're storing all sums of `member_records` in one go: in the `member_record_sums` method. We are also using an instance variable to store the results so that subsequent calls to the method do not query the database.

From there, all we have to do is define our sum-lookup methods dynamically.

Comment: Hi, Humza, thank for your answer. Explanation are clear! However, I still got some problem. I get message below: `> m.member_record_assist_sum
  MemberRecord Load (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM(member_records.assist) AS assist, SUM(member_records.block) AS block FROM "member_records" WHERE "member_records"."member_id" = $1  [["member_id", 123]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `assist' for #<MemberRecord::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fa1bcdf8a08>
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'`

Comment: Yeah, there was an error in my code. I had to add in a `first` as well. Updated code. Should work now.

Comment: I got a strange problem. 
Because the comment character limit, please visit the gist. https://gist.github.com/zxlai/fbd85ca546a32d1f58df

Comment: The error is the same as before: `NoMethodError`. You've probably not copied the code correctly.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the code again. It seems that I copied the code correctly. Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/zxlai/fbd85ca546a32d1f58df

Comment: It appears that the query is ordering by a column that we aren't selecting. So change the line to `self.member_records.select(sums_str).order(MR_SUM_COLUMNS.first).first`

Comment: Excuse me, I read it again. There is one thing I can't figure out. Why you use `member_record_sums.send(column)` instead of `member_record_sums`?

Comment: `member_record_sums` will return all the sums. we want to extract a particular column's sums. for example, for `assist`, we would do this: `member_record_sums.assist`. if you have `"assist"`, you can just pass that like `member_record_sums.send("assist")` and it'll be equivalent to `member_record_sums.assist`

Comment: Thank for your explanation. well, I understand that `member_record_sums.send("assist")` is equivalent to `member_record_sums.assist`. However, where do the method `assist` define? Do I miss anything?

Comment: `sums_str` variable. inspect it. it selects the sum of assist-columns as a single `assist` column. it treats other columns the same way. have a `puts(sums_str)` in there or use `byebug` to properly inspect code and learn what is really going on. that's all the advice i can provide.